# How to pass a parameter to a event's handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to pass a parameter to a event's handler?

Here's what am trying to do, but it doesn't work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
myobj[i].onmouseover = myfun(myobj[i]);
}
```

The following doesn't work neither:

```
myobj[i].onmouseover = myfun.call(myobj[i]);
myobj[i].onmouseover = function () {myfun(myobj[i]);};
myobj[i].onmouseover = function () {myfun.call(myobj[i]);};
```

Am primarily interested in why it doesn't work, and solution in the same style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a creator function for your handlers to encapsulate the parameter to pass on.

```
function createHandler( param ) {
  return function() {
    myfun( param );
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
  myobj[i].onmouseover = createHandler( myobj[i] );
}
```

The reason your approach doesn't work is, because you don't pass on a function reference, but the result of a function call. So in your first example `myfun( myobj[i] )` is evaluated and the result is passed on as the event handler.

I think, what you really mean is, that in case the event is fired, the function shall be evaluated. To do so you either have to pass the parameter via some global var or as a [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset).

The cleaner solution, however, is to have a generator function as shown above.

Comment: PS follow up question. Am what i'm doing ok, is there a idiomatic way to do this? basically i have a bunch of span.xyz elements, i want all of them to have a mouseover behavior. (but not using JQuery or any other)

Comment: @XahLee As long as you're not using any library, I think, thats the best appraoch.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the fact that `onmouseover` will be invoked as a **method** (not a function) on the DOM element which fires the event.

In other words, write your code as if you expected someone to do this:

```
obj = xahlees();
obj.onmouseover();
```

Here's a solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
  myobj[i].onmouseover = function() { myFun(this) };
}
```

I've uploaded a [more complete example](https://gist.github.com/2489155) .

Comment: kinda late, but that's also a great solution. Thanks Leonel.